# Are there any optional areas?

Tags: dark-souls-3

So I just arrived at what I assume is the [last area of the game](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Kiln+of+the+First+Flame), but I know Souls games always have an optional area or two, like [Ash Lake](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/ash-lake) in Dark Souls 1.  I've come across at least two so far ([one of which was hidden](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Smouldering+Lake)). Before I proceed to the final boss I want to make sure I visit all the areas in the game, since I don't want to miss out on any content.

Are there any optional areas in the game? If so, how do you get to them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 4 optional areas:

1. Smouldering lake  - get here from climbing down the broken rope bridge in catacombs of carthus.
2. Consumed King's Garden - after the Dancer of the Boreal Valley boss, head left before getting to lothric castle proper.
3. Untended Graves - behind an illusionary wall after the boss fight in Consumed King's Garden.
4. Archdragon Peak - use Path of the Dragon Gesture in Irithyll Dungeon at the petrified dragon acoylyte.